# drush: list of update-locked modules

Tags: drush

We excluded some modules from drush update (--lock=module_name). Is there a way to get a list of locked modules? A drush command or a file with the list?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this via Drush; the easiest way to find the locked files is with the `find` command:

`find . -name ".drush-lock-update"`

Answer (score 2):

If listing the locked Drupal modules is something you do often you can create a [drush shell alias](http://www.drush.org/en/master/shellaliases/).

Add the following code to your [drushrc.php](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!drush!examples!example.drushrc.php/7) file. Your personal one is normally located at ~/.drush/drushrc.php There are 6 locations that drush will look for drushrc.php, see the [example.drushrc.php](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!drush!examples!example.drushrc.php/7) file for more information.

```
$options['shell-aliases']['locked-modules'] = '! find . -name ".drush-lock-update"| sed \'s#/[^/]*$##\' | sed \'s!.*/!!\' ';
```

You can then run,

```
drush locked-modules
```

to see a list of locked modules. The code above in addition to finding the .drush-lock-update files strips this filename off and then strips off all but the module name from the path.